# Problemas de creación de consulta de Excel hasta el SQL

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente duda se puede generar una consulta de lo cual se llame los datos que contenga una hoja de Excel por ejemplo:

```
select * from TablaExcel
```

donde TablaExcel es lo que contiene la información del Excel, por qué quiero hacer esto ya que tengo una lista de datos de lo cual supera a los 200 datos y las restricciones que tengo es no podre crear una tabla, vistas y procedimiento, por ende quisiera saber si hay manera de extraer los datos de un excel al sql mediante una consulta.

Comment: No, en realidad no puedes hacer consultas a un Excel de esa manera en el servidor de SQL, lo que sí puedes es crear en Excel  (en VBA) un procedimiento que vaya leyendo cada fila y haciendo los INSERT. Vas a requerir la extensión ADO. Varios ejemplos acá https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293669/insert-new-records-only-into-sql-table-using-vba dinos si podemos ayudarte más cuando tengas tu código, si es que te atoras. Y si lo resuelves, comparte aquí tu solución.

Answer (score 1):

Hasta dónde sé, hay dos formas de leer una planilla Excel.

#### 1. Mediante un `linked server`:

Básicamente un `linked server` es una conexión de datos a una fuente externa, normalmente otro servidor `sqlserver`, pero también a otros motores (`mysql`, `oracle`, etc) o fuentes de datos `oledb`, que permite la conexión con archivos físicos, desde planillas  `Excel`, bases `Access`o incluso los viejos y queridos archivos `Dbase` entre otros. Para crear un `linked server` lo puedes hacer desde el `Management Studio` en la opción `Server Objects -> Linked Server` o bien mediante `sp_addlinkedserver`. Lo fundamental de la configuración es seleccionar el provider `Oledb` y configurar luego el path al archivo físico.

El acceso luego es similar al de cualquier otra tabla, solo que hay agregar un dato más al esquema, que es el nombre del `linked server`, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM linkedserver_name…Sheet1$ AS xl
```

`Sheet1` es el nombre de la solapa del `Excel` a leer. Esta opción tiene sus ventajas en un proceso repetitivo y dónde la planilla siempre sea la misma.

#### 2. Mediante `openrowset()`.

Es una alternativa algo más simple y más elegante, a diferencia del `linked server` nos permite acceder a múltiples archivos según la demanda, pero requiere reconfigurar el servidor ya que por defecto no es posible ejecutar consultas distribuidas. Si tienes los permisos adecuados, puedes en primer lugar intentar configurar esto mediante:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'Ad hoc dis'
```

Es probable que esto te dé un error, lo cual significa que el servidor no está configurado para mostrarte los parámetros avanzados. Para resolver esto:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'Show Advanced', 1
RECONFIGURE
```

Y luego:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'Ad hoc dis', 1
RECONFIGURE
```

Una vez configurado esto, es bastante sencillo construir una consulta a cualquier archivo `Excel`:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Tmp\MiPlanilla.xlsx;', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

Notas:

- El `provider` (la cadena `'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'`) puede variar de acuerdo a tu instalación.
- El servidor debe disponer de los drivers `Oledb` en lo posible los más actualizados
- Cuando debas configurar el archivo, debes entender que el mismo es local al servidor y no a tu equipo, cuando tratas de leer `c:\tmp\planilla.xlsx`, la carpeta `c.\Tmp` no es la de tu equipo sino la del servidor.

Información adicional de referencia:

- [Using OPENROWSET to Read Excel Worksheets from SQL Server: Part 1 – How to Set Up the System](https://blog.learningtree.com/using-openrowset-to-read-excel-worksheets-from-sql-server-part-1-setting-up-the-system/)
- [Using OPENROWSET to Read Excel Worksheets from SQL Server: Part 2 – How to Define and Query a Linked Server](https://blog.learningtree.com/using-openrowset-to-read-excel-worksheets-from-sql-server-part-2-linked-sql-queries/)
- [Cómo poder consultar los datos de Excel utilizando servidores vinculados a SQL Server](https://www.sqlshack.com/es/como-poder-consultar-los-datos-de-excel-utilizando-servidores-vinculados-a-sql-server/)
- [Code to read xlsx sheet into a table in a SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150739/code-to-read-xlsx-sheet-into-a-table-in-a-sql-server-database)