# ¿Puede SQL SERVER automáticamente importar los registros de una tabla de EXCEL?

Tags: sql-server-2017

He visto que de forma manual se puede, pero será que existe alguna función dentro de SQL SERVER que realice dicha acción sin tener que de manera manual hacerlo cada cierto tiempo? O tal vez existe alguna aplicación externa que lo pueda hacer?

Esto se debe a que los registros de la tabla en EXCEL estan agregandose hora tras hora. Y no se puede estar pegado a SQL SERVER haciéndolo cada vez de forma manual.

Mil gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Esto tal vez te ayude: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/312135/31764

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo verificaré.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre que tengas una versión que no sea Express, entonces puedes disponer del agente Sql. Este puede, por ejemplo invocar a un paquete SSIS, que recoja, lo que tenga el excel y lo inserte.
Es lo que detallo en este artículo, pero en vez de ejecutarlo en el último paso, puedes guardarlo en un paquete en el almacen de SSIS de Sql server.
[Importar desde Excel a Sql Server](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/09/02/importar-desde-excel-a-sql-server-facil-y-rapido/)
Luego un job del agente, que invoque el paquete, tantas veces como quieras.
Un vistazo rápido al agente, te permitirá incluir el paquete anterior.
[Programar Agente Sql](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/17/agente-sql-programar-sentencias-sql/)

Así lo podrías realizar.